# Combing CASE WHEN with NVL() and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I do a `CASE WHEN` in my SELECT to convert any null into `'None'`. I also want to take a specific non-null value (e.g. `'X'`) and treat this the same as the null values (e.g. make them all `'None'`).

I do something like this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END ValCol
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Val
```

What I end up with is two rows of 'None'; in essence the two 'None' values are being treated separately.

How do I combine them?

Comment: Why not simply SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: By the way, this issue will apply when aggregating any expression, not just `case` and `nvl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `GROUP BY`. You are grouping by `Val`, so all rows with `Val` as `X` are grouped together and all rows where `Val IS NULL` are grouped together. This actually results in 2 rows, but are displayed with the same value because of your `CASE` expression.

You can solve this by grouping with your `CASE` instead of `Val`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END ValCol
FROM 
    tbl
GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END
```

As side note, I find the following `CASE` a little more expressive:

```
CASE WHEN Val = 'X' OR Val IS NULL THEN 'None' ELSE Val END
```

Comment: Brilliant. Now you mention it, I've actually seen this before.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END ValCol
FROM tbl
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. EzLo also had the same idea. I've marked his as the correct answer because it offered more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the expression instead of the column in the GROUP BY clause like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END ValCol
  FROM tbl
 GROUP 
    BY CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END
```

A second way is to use a sub select for the CASE and to group  in an outer select

```
SELECT ValCol
  FROM(SELECT CASE WHEN Val = 'X' THEN 'None' ELSE NVL(Val, 'None') END ValCol
         FROM tbl
      )
 GROUP
    BY ValCOL
```

I would prefer the second way because it's more readable.